# XMLのDTD内でのエラーについて

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE class [ 
<!ELEMENT player (goals+, assists+)>
<!ELEMENT goals (((1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|9)?(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|9)*))>
<!ELEMENT assists (((1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|9)?(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|9)*))>
<!ATTLIST player name CDATA #REQUIRED region CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<player name="Messi" region="Argentina">
    <goals>26</goals>
    <assists>16</assists>
</player>
```

上記のコードに対して，Eclipseから「A '(' character or an element type is required in the declaration of element type "goals".」というエラーメッセージが表示されます．
「'('または要素型が要素型定義内に要求されている．」ということのように思えますが，どういうことでしょうか？
goal要素内は文字列なので`#PCDATA`をどこかに入れるべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

要素名として数値で始まる名前は使用できないので、そのように書くことはできません。

実際の中身は文字なので（おそらく数字縛りをDTDで指定することはできません）

```
<!ELEMENT goals (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT assists (#PCDATA)>
```

のようにします。